# How to copy or export/import LXDE custom color schemes (set via LXAppearance) to another Ubuntu inistance

Tags: themes, lxde, colors

Say you have tweaked your (L)UBUNTU LXDE scheme for hours and it is now perfectly to your liking (using LXAppearance). How can it be copied to your other Ubuntu operated machines (also running LXDE)?

Importing icons / widgets from existing sets is clear to me. But (esp. the color-scheme!) export is a mystery to me (I tried Googling, but I can only find how to SET the colors, which I already know.

I do not want to have to re-invent the wheel with each Ubuntu install.

Comment: I'd expect a simple .lxappearance file somewhere (but could not find such a thing in my homedir, maybe some obscure naming was used?).

Comment: What do you mean by color? You meant by going to __Customize Look and Feel__ 's Color tab?

Comment: _YES_ explicitly that one (that is starting LXAppearance, if I am not mistaking). But I'm fine with CLI too (if knew where/what). Surely it store's its settings _some_ where.

Comment: @woosint Added an answer. You can copy that file in another location

Comment: Also: If I knew how to export colors I'd even love to share it with my friends or the whole community for that matter (not that the latter group would be interested probably; as most of us like to do stuff ourselves :P But hey.. if I can help and make _some_ one happy with it I'd be delighted). The alternative is note the colors by hand; and put them up in a "note"/text-file on github or something like that. But that would still mean manual copying each individual color-code to the config of (L)Ubuntu (or other lxde facilitated linux desktop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings for Lubuntu colors when you change them by going to **Customize Look & Feel** -> **Colors** are stored in the file below (hover over the empty line)

```
~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/desktop.conf
```

So, to restore the settings, you need to copy the file in `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/desktop.conf` to other computer with same name.

**Note:** If you're using other LXDE session, you might find the file in `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/desktop.conf`

Comment: _YES!_  And confirmed for Lubuntu (it may vary a little per distro; e.g. I found it for Debian on: `/.config/lxsession/LXDE`, but all in that area). Thanks a bunch @Anwar and others possibly already searching behind the scenes (I kind of feel guilty even, surely this is documented somewhere on the net). =)

Comment: @woosting great to know